# svn ros revision 17341

Tags: ros, source, svn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For cross-compiling ros, I used svn and it downloaded this revision. But can someone please tell me which version this is (e.g. Electric, Fuerte, ... ) ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76510/svn-ros-revision-17341/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-09-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-05**:
What url are you looking at?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2013-09-05**:
this is the url: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/tags/latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is a very old repo, kept for historical/archive purposes only.  It's version 1.1.8 in that tag which is CTurtle (http://www.ros.org/news/2010/06/ros-118-released-feature-frozen.html)

I highly recommend you look at some of the recent work of others on cross compiling more recent versions of ROS [using Open Embedded](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2013-September/067933.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2013-09-09**:
Thank you for your info. That is very old indeed. Looking at OpenEmbedded.